Conditional probability of dependent variables
The problem:
If $P(A > Bx | B) = 1 - \frac{Bx}{K}$ and $P(B > Ax | A) = 1 - \frac{Ax}{K}$, what is the probability of $P\Big( (A > Bx) \cap (B > Ax)\Big)$?
Given: $0 < x < 1$, $~~~0 < (A,B) < K$, $~~(A,B) \sim U(0,K)$.

My attempt so far:
Since $(A,B) \sim U(0,K)$, the probability density functions (PDF) of $A$ and $B$ are $f(A) = f(B) = \frac{1}{K}$.
Using the law of total probability (if I understood correctly), we get:
$P(A>Bx) = P(B>Ax) = \int_{0}^{K} P(A > Bx | B) f(B)~\mathrm{d}B\\= \int_{0}^{K} P(B > Ax | A) f(A)~\mathrm{d}A = 1 - \frac{x}{2}$.
Therefore, the sought answer should be:
$P\Big( (A > Bx) \cap (B > Ax)\Big) \\= \int_{0}^{K} \int_{0}^{K} P\Big( (A > Bx | B) \cap (B > Ax | A)\Big) f(A>Bx) f(B>Ax) ~\mathrm{d}A ~\mathrm{d}B$
At this stage, I am lost about how to determine $f(A>Bx), f(B>Ax)$ from the available information.

Please help and/or point out if I have been wrong so far. Thanks in advance.

$P\Big( (A > Bx) \cap (B > Ax)\Big)=P(A > Bx)-P(B < Ax)=1-x$

Thanks, that works. That was nice and simple, stupid of me to not have figured it out from the principle of inclusion and exclusion; thanks a lot.
